# Android: Parse dynamic HTML content to String

Tags: java, android, webview

I need to retrieve the contents of an HTML page [such as this](http://live-timing.com/race2.php?r=163390) and store them to a `String` to further parse it using JSoup. The problem is that the contents are dynamically generated from JavaScript, and despite all my research I can't seem to find a solution.

So far I've tried using an invisible `WebView` and adding a `JavaScriptInterface` so that the contents are retrieved, like so:

```
webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new HTMLListener(), "HTMLOUT");

String UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
settings.setUserAgentString(UA);

WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                                  Bitmap favicon) {
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("Load", "load finished");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }

    };

webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

And the HTMLListener class:

```
private class HTMLListener {

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {

        doSomethingWithHTML(html);
    }
}
```

Now this used to work (somehow - I know this solution is majorly hackish) on API18, but the WebView behaviour changed in one of the later APIs (API 21 IIRC). It seems like the onPageFinished method is now executed asynchronously and fires too early, before the dynamic content is rendered.

Any way to fix this? In fact, any solution that would store dynamic web contents to a `String` would be more than welcome.